# django-tables2 specify different properties for different rows

Tags: python, css, checkbox, django-tables2

I would like to create a table with *django-tables2* such that different rows have different properties.

By default I get either

```
<tr class="odd">
```

or

```
<tr class="even">
```

How can I specify my own class for some of the rows?

Similarly, if I have a CheckBoxColumn and I specify some data for this column, it goes into the *value*:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="col" value="123"/>
```

This is great for figuring out which checkbox was checked. However, how can I set some checkboxes as checked when the table is created?

My scenario: the user picks some rows from a large table. For example, the table has

- orange 1
- orange 2
- apple 5
- orange 3
- apple 4
- cucumber 7
- aaple 1

The user picks *aaple 5* and *cucumber 7*.

Then I would like to display all apples and all cucumbers, since the user picked at least one apple and at least one cucumber. This allows the user to see other relevant entries:

- apple 5
- apple 4
- cucumber 7

However, I would like to highlight the entries actually picked by the user by using css and/or by displaying a checked checkbox:

- **apple 5**
- apple 4
- **cucumber 7**

Comment: I guess this contains a solution for this issue [Conditional statements in Django\_tables2 class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66278795/conditional-statements-in-django-tables2-class-definition)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, let me post my own solution.

I have copied the standard template *table.html* and edited it. I only changed one line:

```
<tbody>
    {% for row in table.page.object_list|default:table.rows %} {# support pagination #}
    {% block table.tbody.row %}
    <tr class="{{ row.tr_class }}">  <!-- CLASS FOR EACH ROW -->
```

instead of

```
    <tr class="{% cycle "odd" "even" %}">
```

This way you can set a different class for each row in the table. It remains to add an invisible column to your table class:

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):
  tr_class=tables.Column(visible=False)
  ... # other columns
```

After that, whenever you are creating a table, you can set any CSS classes for any particular rows. Remember to use the modified template:

```
{% render_table div_table "modifiedtable.html" %}
```

Of course, you can also change the original *table.html*.

Can anybody suggest a more graceful solution?

Overall, I have a feeling that django_tables2 is still missing many important features, so I have to reinvent the wheel every time I am trying to do something nontrivial.

### Define tr_class

To use this, you must use [custom rendering](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#custom-rendering). For example:

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):
 tr_class=tables.Column(visible=False, empty_values=())
 def render_tr_class(self, value):
   if value.chosen == True:
     return 'highlight'
```

And the `tr` would be given the class `highlight`.

Comment: For anyone else coming along, you need to add `empty_values=()` to the column definition i.e.: `tr_class=tables.Column(visible=False, empty_values=())`

Answer (score 5):

I have a very easy workaround for this

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):
    source = tables.Column()

    def render_source(self, value):
        if value == 'some_value':
            return mark_safe("<span class='highlight_this_row'>%s</span>" % (escape(value)))
        else:
            return value
```

Then instead of creating a complete custom HTML page for custom rendering, you could just use *jQuery* to actually highlight the row.

```
$('.highlight_this_row').parent().parent().addClass('highlight');
```

If you don't have a class "highlight" defined, you can define it as:

```
<style>
    .highlight{
        background-color: black
    }
</style>
```

Comment: This my friend is the right answer. Now the possibilities are endless. Thanks!

Comment: simple and elegant solution

Answer (score 4):

There's another way (also not very beautiful), but here you don't have to define a fake column.

First, you extend `django_tables2.rows.BoundRows`:

```
class ColoredBoundRows(BoundRows):
    def __iter__(self):
        for record in self.data:
            row = BoundRow(record, table=self.table)
            row.style = 'some_class'
            yield row

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        container = ColoredBoundRows if isinstance(key, slice) else BoundRow
        return container(self.data[key], table=self.table)
```

Then make your Table use it:

```
class YourTable(Table):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourTable, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.rows = ColoredBoundRows(data=self.data, table=self)
```

Then define a new template (note that you only have to overwrite one block):

```
{% extends "django_tables2/table.html" %}

{% block table.tbody.row %}
<tr class="{% cycle "odd" "even" %} {{ row.style }}">
  {% for column, cell in row.items %}
    <td {{ column.attrs.td.as_html }}>{{ cell }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endblock table.tbody.row %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually couldn't get the accepted answer to work for this, perhaps the latest version of django_tables2 is different. Here is my solution, which doesn't require modifying the `tables.html` template and is based on the [documentation](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/column-attributes.html).

First define `row_attrs` as part of the class Meta

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):
    my_column = tables.Column()

    class Meta:
        row_attrs = {'class': my_custom_row_attrs}
```

You can then define a function outside the scope of `MyTable` to work out your row attributes depending on the values in the individual row `record`

```
def my_custom_row_attrs(**kwargs):
    '''My function to generate custom row attributes
    '''

    record = kwargs.get('record', None)
    tr_class = ''

    if record:
        # Only do comparison if pat_date is present
        if record.my_column.value == True:
            tr_class = 'highlight'

    return tr_class
```

I would rather keep all this functionality within the class, but this seemed the best way to do it to avoid modifying anything else.