# set attribute of a row in django-tables2 to record.id

Tags: django-tables2

I am trying to set an attribute of a row in django-tables2 to id of a current record.

To do so I have modified one row in table.html template in such a way:

```
<tr row_id="{{ record.id }}" class="{{ forloop.counter|divisibleby:2|yesno:"even,odd" }}">
```

But this gives me empty row_id="" in html result. What is wrong?

Comment: can you comment on whether the suggestion below worked for you, or if you found a different way?

Comment: Hi! I have not tested the suggestion. I used attribute of a cell for my tasks.

Answer (score 2):

The tables2 `row` object is not the record.. but the record is within it.  So you can do:

```
<tr id="row_{{ row.record.id }}" class="{{ forloop.counter|divisibleby:2|yesno:"even,odd" }}">
```

Or using a data property

```
<tr data-record-id="row_{{ row.record.id }}" class="{{ forloop.counter|divisibleby:2|yesno:"even,odd" }}">
```

This definitely works.. I am using it.

Also look at the (last) answer here: [django-tables2 specify different properties for different rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525670/django-tables2-specify-different-properties-for-different-rows) which suggests using a custom render method to add some html to a cell within each row.  That way you don't have to maintain a custom tables2 template.  Then with help from jquery it's easy enough to find the element containing the id.. if the user clicks on the row, or whatever it is that you'd like to do...

Answer (score 0):

The default name for the for variable for django-tables2 `table.html` (as we see at `https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/templates/django_tables2/table.html#L25`) is `row` (and not `record` which is used for `TemplateColumn`).

You've not shared your `table.html` template however I think that this probably why you see an empty `row_id`. So can you try changing `row_id="{{ record.id }}"` to `row_id="{{ row.id }}"` ?

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work (came back with row_id="-").

Comment: Does your data actually have a field named "id" ?

Comment: yes, it does. (note that SO won't let me just post 'yes' because it's not enough characters)

Comment: it also doesn't work with another model that has a primary key set to be a string. in that case I just get `row_id` and nothing.